# Is 'less riskier than' correct or 'less risky than'?

Tags: comparative-constructions

Using comparative forms while making comparisons only seems natural. However, Microsoft Word (Office 365) suggests 'less risky than' over 'less riskier than'. I know I can replace it with 'safer than' but why isn't 'less riskier than' correct? Or is it?

Comment: Internet searches also seem to favor 'less risky than' over 'less riskier than'.

Comment: _Less_ already indicates the comparative, so you need the standard form of the adjective _risky_ rather than the comparative _riskier_. Similarly, you would say _more safe_ rather than _more safer_.

Comment: Thank you, @KateBunting.

Comment: two-syllable words: less risky, more risky than but: more beautiful than, less beautiful than.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The suffix "-er" means "more". "Less" is the opposite of "more", so "less" + "-er" is always wrong in standard English.

Further, "less" includes the meaning of "comparative", as does "-er", so including "-er" is redundant, which is why "more" + "-er" is also wrong.

Comment: When a comparative form is available, should it be used instead of using *more* or *less*? For example, is 'riskier' is more appropriate than 'more risky'?

Comment: Generally speaking, yes, the -er form is preferred where it is available. Some style guides insist on it, and standardized tests may mark you down for something like "more risky".

Answer (score 0):

For the comparative of inferiority there's no difference between long and short adjectives, we use "less" for both. And after "less", the adjective or adverb is invariable. So you should say: less risky than; less safe than, less kind than, less fast than, less slow than... And not : less riskier than; less safer than...